# Duas rotinas simultaneas

Tags: lua

Como faço para executar duas rotinas simultaneamente no mesmo programa?
Estou tentando baixar um arquivo, e imprimir um valor enquanto estiver baixando.
Exatamente isso:

```
http = require "socket.http"
function downloadFile(url)
download = http.request(url)
return download
end
repeat
print("--")
until downloadFile("http://pokedg/patch/1.7z")
```

Mas retorna apenas:

```
--
```

E acaba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua não permite multitarefas preemptivas, somente corotinas, que são multitarefas colaborativas.

A menos que a biblioteca de `socket.http` permita downloads simultâneos, a única solução é executar estados Lua totalmente separados em threads separados. (Threads do sistema operacional, não de Lua.)

Comment: Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: @GabrielSales, você precisa saber criar e executar threads separados. Uma vez feito isso, crie um estados Lua em cada um deles e rode Lua normalmente.

Comment: Achei o que precisava, obrigado.
http://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html

Comment: @GabrielSales, ótimo! Eu tinha me esquecido disso... Sugiro você adicionar uma resposta explicando isso.